# Persistent SimpleCookie

Tags: python-3.x, cookies

I'm trying to store a persistent cookie with SimpleCookie, so that I'm doing something like:

```
def add_cookie(self, name, value, expiry = None):
  self.cookies[name] = value
  if expiry is not None:
    self.cookies[name]['expires'] = expiry
  print(self.cookies[name].OutputString())
```

Output of print:

```
remember_me=blabla; expires=Sun, 02 Jul 2017 13:30:57 GMT
```

Of course then it's passed to wsgiref.simple_server's start_response function, with something like

```
(Set-Cookie, cookie['remember_me'].OutputString())
```

and the cookie is created on browser/client side, however expiry time is not updating.

Any idea how to set the correct expiry time and make persistent cookie instead of session cookie?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, the described method is fine, I was just rewriting the expiry next time automatically, and that's why expiry disappeared always.